# Displaying FrameTicks of each function

Tags: plotting, homework

Plot f(x) = x^3 and g(x) = 10e^(−x^2) on the same graph. Make a frame around the graph, show tick labels on all four sides, plot such that f(x)’s ticks appear on the left side of the plot and g(x)’s ticks appear on the right side.

I've tried variations of this

```
p5 = x^3
p6 = 10*Exp[-x^2]
Plot[{p5, p6}, {x, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, 
FrameTicks -> {{{p5, p6}, {Automatic, Automatic}}}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

"13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)"

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] = x^3;
g[x_] = 10*Exp[-x^2];
```

With v12.0 and later, use `ResourceFunction["MultipleAxesPlot"]`

```
Show[
 maplt = ResourceFunction["MultipleAxesPlot"][
   {f[x], g[x]}, {x, -1, 1},
   PlotStyle -> {{GrayLevel[0.3], AbsoluteThickness[1]}, ColorData[97][2]},
   FrameLabel -> {
     {StringForm["`` = ``", HoldForm[f[x]], f[x]], 
      StringForm["`` = ``", HoldForm[g[x]], g[x]]},
     {x, None}},
   "SecondaryAxesColor" -> ColorData[97][2]],
 (Options[maplt, FrameTicks] /. {} :> Automatic)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
p5 = x^3;
p6 = 10*Exp[-x^2];
```

Find the minimum and maximum values for `p5` (`yrange5`) and `p6` (`yrange6`) and  use them (1) to [`Rescale`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rescale.html) `p6`  and (2) to define a *ticks function* for the right frame:

```
{yrange5, yrange6} = Through[{MinValue, MaxValue}[{#, -1 <= x <= 1}, x]] & /@ {p5, p6};

rescaledp6 = Rescale[p6, yrange6, yrange5];

rightframeticks = Charting`FindTicks[yrange5, yrange6];
```

Plot `{p5, rescaledp6}` with the option `FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, rightframeticks}, {Automatic, Automatic}}`:

```
Plot[{p5, rescaledp6}, {x, -1, 1}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel->{{p5, p6}, {x, None}}, 
 FrameStyle -> {ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, rightframeticks}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image]